# bare minimum atom tags required for feed validity

Tags: atom-feed

What is the bare minimum tags required for an atom feed to be valid? I admit I haven't finished reading the specification yet, but thought that a short summary would be nice for me and anyone else looking for a short, clear answer.

Comment: Since no one seems to know (or are unwilling to share): for those of you who aren't able to read the spec, you can use [the w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi) to brute-force your way to conformance. Start out with a feed from any site, and continue from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A  [minimal, valid example](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-1.1) is the first thing in [the Atom specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287). Start with that, then read the rest of the spec to improve your understanding and answer any questions.

Comment: The first link contains the answer I was looking for. I don't know how in the world I missed that, but when I posted my question, I was already delving in the syntax definitions of atom:feed and atom:entry. That explains the many -well deserved- down votes I got.