# Rails atom feed validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, builder, atom-feed

I'm trying to generate atom feed for special offers.
The controller works fine so the link `http://localhost:3000/offers.atom` render some xml.
I have a list of offers in `http://localhost:3000/offers` page. For each offer I don't have the show page becouse the original product is in an other web site. So in `http://localhost:3000/offers` page I'm only listing the offers but if I click in a specific offer I'm redirected to another web site.

My problem is generating the atom xml file:

```rails
#app/views/offers/index.atom.builder
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title "title"
  feed.updated @offers.maximum(:updated_at)
  @offers.each do |offer|
    feed.entry(offer, url: offer.product_link) do |entry|
      entry.image image_tag(offer.img_link)
      entry.title offer.desc
      entry.description offer.desc
      entry.price offer.price
      entry.special_price offer.special_price
      entry.saving offer.saving
    end
  end
end
```

The [validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/#validate_by_input) find some errors in my xml file.
This is my xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>tag:localhost,2005:/offers</id>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://localhost:3000"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://localhost:3000/offers.atom"/>
  <title>title</title>
  <updated>2014-04-08T12:33:24Z</updated>
  <entry>
    <id>tag:localhost,2005:Offer/116</id>
    <published>2014-04-08T12:33:24Z</published>
    <updated>2014-04-08T12:33:24Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://e-commerce.centroservizirovigo.com/Detail.aspx?ProductId=2101845"/>
    <img>&lt;img alt="738750a1" src="http://e-commerce.centroservizirovigo.com//Images/1480/738750A1.jpg" /&gt;</img>
    <title>​Rilegatrice termica T400 GBC - 400 fogli - 4400411</title>
    <description>​Rilegatrice termica T400 GBC - 400 fogli - 4400411</description>
    <price>167.7</price>
    <special_price>124.0</special_price>
    <saving>26.1</saving>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

But I have no idea to solve.

Comment: I don't think anybody would've any idea if you don't post what the errors are.

Comment: Copy and past the xml in the validator. The errors are to verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors seem clear:

```
Undefined entry element: img
Undefined entry element: description
Undefined entry element: price
...
```

These are elements that you have used which are not defined by the Atom spec. They can't appear in your document unless you put them in a separate namespace (as [Extensions from Non-Atom Vocabularies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-6.1)).

```
Missing entry element: author
Missing textual content
```

The Atom spec requires a minimum set of fields ([bare minimum atom tags required for feed validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371013/bare-minimum-atom-tags-required-for-feed-validity)). You'll need to include them for a valid feed.